# Processing help. Trying to create more objects like the object I currently have already

Tags: processing, computer-science

I'm new to using processing and I've been trying to make an object move randomly across my sketch for some time now. I have finally finished that part and are able to have it move randomly. The only thing is, I need 3 of these objects but I only have 1. I tried using an array but didn't have any luck. My current project is to game where you control an object (turkey) with arrow keys and have to lead it across the sketch to the house to win. But between you and the house are 3 hunters. These 3 hunters have to move randomly. I got one to move randomly but now I need two more and I tried using an array and couldn't get it to work. My code very well may be a mess but I am so confused right now.

```
int radius = 30, directionX = 1, directionY = 0;
float x=20, y=20, speed=5;
PImage turkey;

Hunter[] hunters = new Hunter[3];
// =========================================================
void setup()
{
  size(1600,900);
  smooth();
  fill (color(222, 22, 22));
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  turkey = loadImage("Turkey.png");
  random = new Hunter[3];
  random[1] = new Hunter(color(0, 255, 0), 
    (float)(width/444), (float)(height/2), 5f);
}
void draw()
{
  background(255);
  random[1].display();
  random[1].walkRandom();
  // changing Position
  x=x+speed*directionX;
  y=y+speed*directionY; 
  // check boundaries
  if ((x>width-radius) || (x<radius))
  {   
    directionX=-directionX;
  }
  if ((y>height-radius) || (y<radius))
  {   
    directionY=-directionY;
  } 
  // draw
  fill (color(222, 22, 22)); 
  ellipse (x, y, radius, radius);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(turkey,x,y);
  // body
}
// =========================================================
void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == CODED)
  {
    if (keyCode == LEFT)
    {
      directionX=-1;
      directionY=0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == RIGHT)
    {  
      directionX=1;
      directionY=0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == UP)
    {
      directionY=-1;
      directionX=0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == DOWN)
    {
      directionY=1;
      directionX=0;
    }
  }
}


////////////////////////////////////


class HunterOne{

  int colour;
  float xPos;
  float yPos;
  float xSpeed;
  float ySpeed;

  HunterOne(int colour, 
    float xPos, float yPos, 
    float xSpeed) {
    this.colour = colour;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
  }

  public void display() {      
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(colour);
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);
  }

  public void walkRandom() {

    xPos = xPos + xSpeed;
    yPos = yPos + ySpeed;

    if (xPos > width) {     
      xPos = width;
      PVector newMovment = new PVector(-5f, 0);
      xSpeed = newMovment.x;
      ySpeed = newMovment.y;
    }
    if (yPos > height) {
      yPos = height;
      // PVector newMovment = doTheThingBottom();
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }
    if (xPos < 0) {
      xPos = 0;
      xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }
    if (yPos < 0) {
      yPos = 0;
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }

    // random turn
    if (random(100)>97) {
      PVector newMovment = doTheThing();
      xSpeed = newMovment.x;
      ySpeed = newMovment.y;
    }
  }

  PVector doTheThing() {

    // random turn

    PVector result=new PVector(0, 0);

    int randomDirection = int (random(4));

    switch(randomDirection) {

    case 0:
      // Up
      result = new PVector(0, -5f);
      break;

    case 1:
      // Left
      result = new PVector(-5f, 0);
      break;

    case 2:
      // Down
      result = new PVector(0, 5f);
      break;

    case 3:
      // Right
      result = new PVector( 5f, 0);
      break;

    default:
      // error 
      println("error 63");
      result = new PVector( 5f, 0);
      break;
    }//switch  

    return result;
  }
} // class 
HunterOne[] random;
public void settings() {
  size(1600, 900);
  smooth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Processing (which is Java), there is no operator to create copy of an object. Unlike C++, in Processing, if we use assignment operator then it will create a **copy of reference variable and not the object**.

So you have to clone your object, here is example ([source](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20793/how-to-create-an-independent-clone-of-an-object)):

```java
void setup(){
  book bookOne = new book("Nineteen Eighty-Four", "George Orwell", 1949);
  book bookTwo = bookOne.clone();

  bookTwo.title="Animal Farm";
  bookTwo.year=1945;

  //Prints "Animal Farm by George Orwell published in 1945" which is correct.
  println(bookTwo.title+" by "+bookTwo.author+" published in "+bookTwo.year);

  //Also prints "Nineteen Eighty-Four by George Orwell published in 1949" correctly now
  println(bookOne.title+" by "+bookOne.author+" published in "+bookOne.year);

}

class book {
 String title;
 String author;
 int year;

 book(String t, String a, int y){
   title=t;
   author=a;
   year=y;
 }

 book clone(){
  book newBook = new book(title, author, year);
  return newBook;
 }
}
```